# Can you prevent Excel for adjusting column widths when doing an export from sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel

My list and reports are fairly large.  Now that I have converted the MS Office 2013 I've noticed everytime I try to do an export from my SharePoint lists even a small export it takes a long time to export because it is adjusting column widths.  It seems to be stuck on this everytime and taking twice the amount of time to refresh reports and do exports from a list.  Any suggestions on how to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 2):

In Excel, click into the table, then on the Data ribbon in the Connections group click Properties. That will open a dialog where you can untick the option "Adjust column width".

Comment: I would love to try this solution, but when I open my iqy query, Excel freezes, and I can't get to the Data ribbon. 

I've tried opening a new excel, Clicking on Insert->Table, but even then, the Properties  option is greyed out. 

What am I missing? Thanks for finding and sharing this solution.